# Hide Menu Item with Eclipse SWT Core Expressions

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have a toolbar menu for a custom multipart editor with two pages. I want some menu items only to apprear when page 1 is in focus and others when page 2 is in focus.

I have defined the toolbar in the plugin.xml and am using the Eclipse Core Expression *activeFocusControlId*  in combination with the *IFocusService*.

I works well when I click on the different pages, but initially all menu items are shown (even when I call setFocus() from the editor code).

**How can I properly init the menu?**

```xml
         <command
               commandId="newInput"
               label="New Entry"
               style="push"
            <visibleWhen
                  checkEnabled="false">
               <with
                     variable="activeFocusControlId">
                  <equals
                        value="inputViewer">
                  </equals>
               </with>
            </visibleWhen>
         </command>
         <command
               commandId="newClassification"
               label="New Classification"
               style="push"
            <visibleWhen
                  checkEnabled="false">
               <with
                     variable="activeFocusControlId">
                  <equals
                        value="classificationViewer">
                  </equals>
               </with>
            </visibleWhen>
         </command>
```

Java Code in the *MultiPageEditorPart's createPages()* method

```java
IFocusService service = (IFocusService)this.getSite().getService(IFocusService.class);
service.addFocusTracker(this.viewer.getGrid(), "inputViewer");
service.addFocusTracker(this.classificationViewer.getGrid(),"classificationViewer" );
```

Comment: There are missing `>` chars on the `<command` elements in your XML - is that real or a typo?

Comment: No, this is just a copy and paste type. The code per-se runs fine, it just does not exactly do what I want.

Comment: Well as shown this is not valid XML - which is why the colouring is shown wrong here.